# How can I resolve this error? Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am developing a react application. I got this error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
I have tried to get a solution from different sources, am still stuck. How do I resolve this problem?
Here is my app.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./containers/Home";
import Login from "./containers/Login";
import Signup from "./containers/Signup";
import Activate from "./containers/Activate";
import ResetPassword from "./containers/ResetPassword";
import ResetPasswordConfirm from "./containers/ResetPasswordConfirm";
import Information_create from "./containers/ClientInformation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

import Layout from "./hocs/Layout";

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route exact path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
         <Route
            exact
            path="/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token"
            component={ResetPasswordConfirm}
          />
          <Route exact path="/activate/:uid/:token" component={Activate} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/information-create"
            component={Information_create}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't think this is the component you are getting errors from. Please find and share the correct components from where you're getting errors.

And what `version` of `react-router-dom`  you are using.

Comment: I am using "react-dom": "^16.13.1",

Comment: not `react-dom` I'm talking about `react-route-dom`

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Answer (score 0):

There must be a use of hook in a class component in your project. Hooks cannot be used in a class component. App.js seems fine. check elsewhere